# append data to table from external csv in excel

Tags: excel, csv, import, append

If I have a table with data in a excel file, how can I append data to that table using the "get external data - from csv". My table last cell is in A3016, I then highlighted the A3017 cell and from that cell choosed "Get external data", the data is imported but it does not belong to the table like it does if I manually add data to the next free cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this VBA code to achieve the desired results:

```
Sub Append_CSV_File()

    Dim csvFileName As Variant
    Dim destCell As Range

    Set destCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)      'CHANGE SHEET NAME

    csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
    If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub

    With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFileName, Destination:=destCell)
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete
    End Sub
```

let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I Wonder if its possible without using vba..?

Comment: If you prefer non VBA approach then you have manually convert the imported data to a Table

Comment: Yes but how can I append to the exsisting tanke?

Comment: Ok you can load the csv data on a different sheet and on last row of the existing table use =Sheet2!A1 this the sheet where the csv data resides and drag down till the end.