# How to import data from csv file to existing pivot-table in excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, pivot-table

my problem is simply i have a csv file in a certain format and i get new data at different times. I need to import the data from the csv file and add it to bottom of existing data table which i have created before then continue like this. As result i am creating pivot table from these csv files.

Can i do it by macro?
As an additional information, csv file always will be placed same directory as excel file.

[my data table something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OByTO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achived to solve problem by below code. Actually i seacrhed a lot but i couldnt find at first. After i posted new question here i have found out answer and have taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536505/append-data-to-table-from-external-csv-in-excel) topic and i changed some up to myself

```
Sub AutoExpand()

Dim csvFileName As Variant
Dim destCell As Range 'destination Cell
Dim lo As ListObject

Set destCell = yourSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'CHANGE SHEET NAME
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub

With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFileName, Destination:=destCell)
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete

Set destCell = yourSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) 
Set lo = yourSheet.ListObjects("table")
lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(destCell.Row) 'Resizing table up to added new data from CSV file
End Sub
```